# Double the number of inserted data to Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm inserting 2 Offices records to Office table in MY DB .

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void insertOffices(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Insert Orange tours.
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getDrawable(R.drawable.orange)).getBitmap();
    byte[] temp = convertImage.bitmapToByte(bitmap);
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFNAME, "اورنج تورز");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFIMAGE, temp);
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFDESC, "شركة سياحة وسفر");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFLOCATION, "بديا" + "الشارع الرئيسي");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFPHONE, "0554544545");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFRATE, "10");

    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(
            DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);

    Log.d("Database", "insertBooks: new record id : " + newRowId);

    db.insert(DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    values.clear();

    //Insert arsema
    Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getDrawable(R.drawable.orange)).getBitmap();
    byte[] temp1 = convertImage.bitmapToByte(bitmap1);
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFNAME, "ارسيما");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFIMAGE, temp1);
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFDESC, "شركة سياحة وسفر");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFLOCATION, "جنين" + "الشارع الرئيسي");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFPHONE, "0554544545");
    values.put(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFRATE, "10");


    newRowId = db.insert(
            DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);

    Log.d("Database", "insertBooks: new record id : " + newRowId);


    db.insert(DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    values.clear();

}
```

getOffices method that select all offices and return a list of offices:

```
 public List<Office> getOffices() {
    List<Office> offices = new ArrayList<Office>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Office office = new Office();
            office.setOfficeID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office._ID))));
            office.setOfficeName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFNAME)));
            office.setOfficeLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFLOCATION)));
            office.setOfficeImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFIMAGE)));
            office.setOfficeDescreption(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFDESC)));
            office.setOfficeRate(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Office.COL_OFFRATE)));

            // Adding offices to list
            offices.add(office);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return offices;
}
```

then I've populated the data to the Offices Activity into offices `RecyclerView` , using custom adapter.

Why this return a list of 4 offices , although I've inserted only 2 offices?

Comment: Its because you inserted it twice in same table .

Comment: Why you put same code twice in method . Do mind debugging before posting question here .

Comment: remove `db.insert(DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME, null, values);`

Comment: @ it's not the same code , each one represents a record @ADM

Comment: You are inserting hardcoded values to `DB` .  If you call `insertOffices` twice then there will be 4 rows created in `DB`. Why don't create a single method with single insert query and call it with different arguments .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **each** of the two records (**//Orange** and **//arsema**) you have **two** inserts as per :-

```
// 1st insert
newRowId = db.insert(
        DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME,
        null,
        values);

Log.d("Database", "insertBooks: new record id : " + newRowId);


//Duplicate insert (albeit with different id)
db.insert(DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Instead use something like (i.e. only 1 insert per) :-

```
//Now just 1 insert
Log.d("Database", 
    "insertBooks: new record id : " + 
        db.insert(DBContract.Office.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
);
```

P.S. perhaps for the second (//arsema) you should be using :-

```
    Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getDrawable(R.drawable.aresma)).getBitmap(); //arsema bitmap not orange bitmap
```